# Why is $\cosh$ used in parametrization of $x^2-y^2=1$ when $\cosh$ can't be negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions, parametrization

I came across a question to parametrize $x^2-y^2=1$. From its similarity to the identity $\cosh^2(t)-\sinh^2(t)=1$, I parametrized as follows.
$$x = \cosh(t), y = \sinh(t)$$
It all seemed fine and the book said it is the answer but I soon realized that $\cosh(t) \geq 1$ for all real number $t$. This made me question the parametrization I came up with, as there are points where $x$ is negative for the graph of $x^2-y^2=1$.

Comment: It's true that your parameterization does not parameterize both arcs of the hyperbola. But because there are two separate arcs, there is no continuous parameterization (with connected domain, anyway) that parameterizes both arcs at once.

Comment: @TravisWillse I am new to parameterization. So are you saying that even if we parameterize just a single arc, it is still considered a correct parameterization? Is there a reason why 'rigorous' mathematicians would allow that?

Comment: @TravisWillse Oh nevermind I guess then there would be two seperate parameterizations for each arc to make a more complete parameterization. That would make things rigorous enough.

Comment: The correct parametrisation is $x = \pm \cosh(t), y= \sinh(t)$, with each choice of sign giving an arc. Note that while $$x=\sec(t), y =\tan(t)$$ seems to be a single parametrisation, when you realize that the domain is an union of infinitely many intervals, and the parametrisation needs to be defined on a SINGLE interval, you see that the trig parametrisation is actually 2 differet parametrisations (one for each arc) repeated periodically.

Comment: @linearAlg Whether it's "correct" depends on what your aim is; often we only need to parameterize some part of a larger shape. For example, in celestial mechanics one of the possible motions of a particle in an inverse-square gravitational field is an arc of a hyperbola---since the particle moves continuously, it never skips from one branch of the hyperbola to the other, and so a function parameterizing its motion would only trace out (some arc) of one branch.

Comment: @N.S. I might avoid the phrase "the correct parameterization", because it suggests other parameterizations might be incorrect. Also, I'm not sure the $\pm$ parameterization you give is so different from the trigonometric one you mention: If we formalize the use of $\pm$ by writing the parameterization as $$x = \mu \cosh t, \quad y = \sinh t , \qquad (\mu, t) \in \{\pm 1\} \times \Bbb R ,$$ our domain still consists of more than connected component, no?

Comment: @TravisWillse I mean the "correct" way to parametrize the curve with hyperbolic functions, not that the hyperbolic is more correct that other. As for the second comment, it was more about why the tangent one is NOT a single parametrisation (while the hyperbolic one looks like 2).

Comment: I understand, thanks for the clarifications---cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your parameterization parameterizes one branch of the hyperbola
$$\{x^2 - y^2 = 1\} ,$$
but like you say, it does not also trace out the other. The same must be true of any continuous parameterization with connected domain, since the image of such a domain under such a map is connected but the other does not.

In general, whether a parameterization $f : X \to Y$ whose image is not all of the target space $Y$ is sufficient for one's needs depends on the context. For example, a point mass in a central (inverse-square) gravitational field on an escape trajectory traces out one branch of a hyperbola: The trajectory function that gives its position as a function of time parameterizes that branch, but not the other (which in this case is nonphysical).

As N.S. suggests in the comments, it's still possible to parameterize the hyperbola if you're willing to tolerate a nonconnected domain, e.g., with the map
$$\alpha: \{\pm 1\} \times \Bbb R , \qquad \alpha(\mu, t) := (\mu \cosh t, \sinh t) .$$